# Missing user logo screen on the unity panel

Tags: 16.04

I didn't know how to say it correctly in the title but i on my Ubuntu I'm missing the profile thing
This is how it should look :
[i found this on Google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuoW7.png)

but for me it looks like this : [this is how it looks for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAcAS.png)

i really have no clue what to do I've tried searching it up but i only found people missing their calendar but nothing like this

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: That is the session indicator, Could you add these outputs to the question `apt-cache policy indicator-session` , `ps aux | grep indicator-session` and `gsettings list-recursively com.canonical.indicator.session`

Answer (score 0):

Open System Settings -- open User Accounts -- tick Show my login name in the menu bar.

Comment: i don't have that option